# Rails - start your route from second element of the path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way in rails to start routing from 2nd part of the url path?

for example `localhost:3000/tenant_name/posts` for `resources:posts`

tenant_name is a name of the schema in my database.i want switch to respective tenant using the tenant_name.

when i run this now will get `No route matches [GET] "/tenant_name/posts"`

I need to visit posts even if replace "tenant_name"with any tenant_name.How to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [scope](https://devblast.com/b/rails-5-routes-scope-vs-namespace) without any options and only a scope name, it will just change the resources path.

```
scope :sometext_here do
  resources :posts
end
```

This will generate url like -

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
 posts GET    /sometext_here/posts(.:format)     posts#index
       POST   /sometext_here/posts(.:format)     posts#create
  post GET    /sometext_here/posts/:id(.:format) posts#show
       PATCH  /sometext_here/posts/:id(.:format) posts#update
       PUT    /sometext_here/posts/:id(.:format) posts#update
       DELETE /sometext_here/posts/:id(.:format) posts#destroy
```

Alternative way to use it -

```
get '/:dynamic_text/posts' => 'posts#index', as: :all_posts
```

So it can be used as

```
all_posts_path(dynamic_text: "sometext_here")
```

Comment: in my case i don't want to pass as parameter.I just want to start the route from /sometext_here onwards...... i will try the first way and let you know if it satisfy my situation.thank you.

Comment: that was nice way.... but the "sometext_here" will change accordingly....

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan In 2nd way by passing "sometext_here" it can be chnaged dynamically otherwise for static it would be convenient way to go with `scope`. Hopefully that make sense. feel free to accept/upvote if it helped you. also let me know for any other guidance. Thanks.

Comment: both of this ways won't help me.Actually the "sometext_here" is my tenant schema name, and if we change it tenant is switched between. i get error due to routing

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan Hmm it wasn't mentioned in question that you asked.